# CakePHP email rendering issue

Tags: php, cakephp, html-email, cakephp-2.3

I am sending htmlmail using **CakeEmail** in myproject. I use a table structure in my email layout file and saved my replaceable text in database. The Mail function works fine, it add the database content to the email layout before send. But the table layout is breaking when I receive the mail. I found out the render function in CakeEmail.php adds `<p>` tags to each line of code which I saved in database.

```
(int) 32 => '   <table  align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >',
(int) 33 => '   <tbody> <tr><td><p> <tr></p>',
(int) 34 => '<p>  <td style="padding:0;margin:0;"></p>',
(int) 35 => '<p>  <h2 style="color:#404040;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;line-height:22px;padding:0;margin:0;letter-spacing:0.015 em; font-family: arial,sans-serif;">Activate Account</h2></p>',
(int) 36 => '<p>   </td></p>',
(int) 37 => '<p>   </tr></p>',
(int) 38 => '<p> </p>',
(int) 39 => ' <tr><td></tbody>',
(int) 40 => ' </table>',
```

How can I send replace the database text without the `<p>`             element.

Database entry is like this

```
<table style="margin-top: 80px" width="630" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >                                 <tbody>                                                              <tr><td style="padding:0;margin:0;">                                                                                <h2 style="color:#404040;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;line-height:22px;padding:0;margin:0;letter-spacing:0.015 em; font-family: arial,sans-serif;">Activate Account</h2>                                                                            </td></tr></tbody>                                                                </table>
```

Comment: IMHO if some of the whitespace columns would be deleted in your code sample, it would add to readability (for this question).

Comment: Check your `<tr>` tags. In line 33 there are 2 opening and in row 39 theres another open one.

Comment: Its not about the tag, it happens with a single tr row. I think its because cake rendering the newline with `<p>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines are wrapped in `<p>` elements in the default HTML email element template, which can be found in `app/View/Emails/html/default.ctp`:

```
$content = explode("\n", $content);

foreach ($content as $line):
    echo '<p> ' . $line . "</p>\n";
endforeach;
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.0/app/View/Emails/html/default.ctp**

Modify the template to your needs, probably you just want to `echo $content;`.